# CSS Transform fixed position element on Android 2.3.3

Tags: android, fixed, translate-animation

I'm trying to slide in and out a fixed position  using translateY(). This works on IOS and all modern desktop browsers, but not on my Android 2.3.3 emulator. The only way I can get it working is to changing the positioning to absolute, but then scrollbars appear. Is there a way to hack this into working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's working in Motorolla XOOM i think this problem with emulator not Android

```
.transofmr
{
transform: rotate(30deg);
-ms-transform: rotate(30deg); /* IE 9 */
-webkit-transform: rotate(30deg); /* Safari and Chrome */
-o-transform: rotate(30deg); /* Opera */
-moz-transform: rotate(30deg); /* Firefox */
}
```